# Resource recommendations for DSP beginners

Tags: books, dsp

I was searching around and I have had some trouble finding some decent resources for an engineer first entering the world of DSP.

What resources (books, tutorials, DVDs, online courses, etc) do you recommend for a Software Engineer (with a basic background in EE) who is entering the DSP world?

I've been reading wikipedia for a while so I've got a fairly high-level overview of what DSP is and how some of the functions work, I'd like to get a bit more in-depth with a lot of the topics though.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59/dsp-recommendation-for-beginners

Comment: I was going to say dupe of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59/dsp-recommendation-for-beginners, but I guess this is about books and that is about eval boards.

Comment: [This is a good intro](http://www.bores.com/courses/intro/), but it's also the first Google hit, so I suppose you've already read it before asking this question?

Comment: @endolith, yeah... but I have my doubts as to if book shopping question is on topic. Also very subjective.

Comment: @Kellenjb I think it's on topic.

Comment: @Sean Madden, you say "I'd like to get a bit more in-depth with a lot of the topics though." what specific topics are you wanting to learn more about?

Comment: @Kellenjb, I know DSP is a wide ranging topic but I'd like to get more in-depth with regard to communications, modulation/demodulation and the theory behind that to start and then move on to other topics as they become apparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When asking this same question myself I was told that "The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing" by Steven W. Smith is quite good. It's free and available online @ http://www.dspguide.com/

Comment: +1 Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although not free, there is one text book that I constantly use when I am trying to work with communication systems. It is called [Digital Communications: Fundamentals and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130847887) by Bernard Sklar.

It is more focused on Communications in general then on DSP, but it does cover DSP techniques for communication systems.

It is the best book I have found for being able to understand the entire scope of communication systems including noise modeling, multiplexing, modulation, multiple access, error control coding... you name it, it has it.